How to Display DWG/DXF File Content in a Flutter Widget also there is 3D view i want to show this 3d view in app?
I'm working on a Flutter application where I need to read and display the contents of CAD files in .dwg and .dxf formats. These files contain architectural drawings and other vector data. I'm looking for a widget or a method in Flutter that can handle these formats and render the content within the app.
I've explored several options, but I couldn't find a direct way to do this. Ideally, I want to be able to:
Load and parse DWG/DXF files.
Display the drawing content (e.g., lines, shapes, text) in a Flutter widget.
Allow basic interaction like zooming and panning.
Does anyone know of a package or method to achieve this in Flutter? Or would I need to use a native solution and integrate it with Flutter? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
I was expecting to find a Flutter widget or package that could load and display DWG/DXF file contents, allowing for basic interactions like zooming and panning.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Unfortunately there is no such package.
You need to use

dxf parser https://pub.dev/packages/dxf
infinite canvas display packages

https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_canvas
https://pub.dev/packages/image_painter etc.
but you will need to implement your own drawing elements: lines, circles, arcs, etc.
if you want to mix your drawing with cartography then this can help you if you use the Cartesian coordinate system
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map
